# Cookie troubles with Chromium

Tags: support, google-chrome, beta-phase, cookies

About every two weeks Stack Overflow won't load. The browser window is plain white and nothing happens.
Reload, forced reload, clear browser cache, restart browser does not help.

If I delete all cookies that start with stackoverflow, the page loads (but it says I am a new user and I have to login again). I haven't tried yet if I really have to clear all Stack Overflow cookies or a subset is enough.

Interestingly, only `stackoverflow.com` is affected, none of the three sisters (I always load them in four tabs). I think it started around beginning of August but I'm not 100% sure.

As I use a rather exotic browser (Chromium on Ubuntu Karmic Koala) and I could not reproduce it on Firefox. I guess this will not be further investigated, but I would be interested if there are other Chrome or Chromium (or even Safari) users out there that have the same issues.

EDIT: Just for the record, since 22. December 2009 it also happens for serverfault, but not superuser or meta.

Comment: is this Chrome v4? That's an unreleased browser..?

Comment: Chromium - 4.0.226.0 (Ubuntu build 30050)

Comment: I am not allowing this as a bug until that's a released browser. Sorry.

Comment: @Jeff: That's OK, I only learnt from the answers that the problem is really specific to this browser or maybe even my configuration.
If I find the cause I'll let you know...

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen it quite like that. I've seen it fail to get any of the JavaScript working, although not for a few weeks.

The only times I've seen a plain blank screen is when my 3G network refuses to connect, and cookies won't help that.

Recently I've seen various Stack sites forget who I am occasionally, but nothing more than that.

I don't use Chromium, but I do use a variety of flavours of Chrome - stable on my main laptop, beta on my netbook, and something close to dev at work on my Linux desktop.

Comment: I haven't had a problem with Chrome on Linux either.

Comment: I can force the SO sites to forget me on a page load by clicking a URL while the site is still loading.  Go ahead and click on meta twice in quick succession.  It then displays the page as though you are not authenticated.  I assume this is related to some JS not completing.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jon, I've had the JavaScript fail to load several times (usually after clearing my cache) in Chrome (v4) on Windows, but nothing to do with cookies. Clearing your cookies should log you out though.

The only way I can get around the JavaScript problem is to manually load all of the JavaScript files and see which one is the problem. Then, I hold ctrl and double click the refresh button (a single click doesn't seem to do it). Once it loads the js file, SO then works as normal. Like you though, I only get this problem on SO and none of the other sites (meta SF, SU), so maybe it has something to do with how SO is specifically set up. I have a similar problem on the BBC news website after clearing the cache.